# Replace special character with double double quotes

Tags: powershell, replace

I have a text file with the some special character `$`, which needs to be replaced by double double quotes. I am using a bat file in which I invoke `powershell.exe` and write the replace command. Below is the command:

```
powershell "gc C:\Temp\Test.csv| foreach-object {$_ -replace '$','""""""'}|sc C:\Temp\Test_Replace.csv"
```

I know that double quotes are escaped by a double quote so """"" is equivalent to "". But as seen in the above code I need to write 6 double quotes to get the equivalent 2 quotes. I cannot figure out the reason for this.

Can Someone please illustrate the point I am missing.

Comment: `-replace` uses regex. escape the `$` (which is the end-of-string special character in regex): `$_ -replace '\$','""""""'`

Comment: Personally, I would call this a bug in `PowerShell.exe` command line parser. The sequence `""` handled very strangely by it, so I recommend not use it, but use `\"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, I think it is a but in `PowerShell.exe` command line parser. When it see `""` inside quoted context, it not only produce literal `"` but also close quoted context:

```
CMD> powershell '"1  2""3  4"'
1  2"3 4
```

As you can see, there is only one space between 3 in 4 in printed string. You need to put extra double quote to reopen quoted context:

```
CMD> powershell '"1  2"""3  4"'
1  2"3  4
```

So, in fact, you have to triplicate double quote to produce just one literal double quote character.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the nested double quote properly. Also, the `ForEach-Object` isn't required. Put the `Get-Content` in an expression (i.e. in parentheses) and you can use the `-replace` operator directly.

```
powershell -Command "(gc C:\Temp\in.csv) -replace '$','\"\"'|sc C:\Temp\out.csv"
```

If you want to replace literal `$` characters instead of adding double quotes to the end of each line you need to escape the `$` as well, as Mathias pointed out:

```
powershell -Command "(gc C:\Temp\in.csv) -replace '\$','\"\"'|sc C:\Temp\out.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for improving the logic. The statement i have provided does the job (getting TWO double quotes for every literal $). But not clear on how the 6 double quotes instead of 4 gets the job done.