# When do backslashes require and escape from cmd Powershell invocation?

Tags: powershell

Why does the first backslash appear in the Powershell variable and the second does not unless escaped?

```
C:>type param001.ps1
param([string]$thedir)
Write-Host $thedir
```

In this case, the first backslash appears, but the final one does not.

```
C:>powershell -NonInteractive .\param001.ps1 """C:\Program Files (x86)\"""
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

Why does it require escaping the last backslash?

```
C:>powershell -NonInteractive .\param001.ps1 """C:\Program Files (x86)\\"""
C:\Program Files (x86)\
```

This question is not the same situation as [Powershell - escaping string passed to child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276662/powershell-escaping-string-passed-to-child-process). That question does not deal with cmd.exe invoking powershell.exe.

Comment: This also works. `powershell -NonInteractive .\param001.ps1 "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\\""`

Comment: The first one is [handled by cmd.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html): `The \ escape can cause problems with quoted directory paths that contain a trailing backslash because the closing quote " at the end of the line will be escaped \".`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - escaping string passed to child process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276662/powershell-escaping-string-passed-to-child-process)

Comment: And I also recommend not to use [`""`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35715121) as literal `"`, but use `\"` instead.

Comment: ``\`` is not a special character for `cmd` and does need any escapement for `cmd` part. And PowerShell command line parsing rules does not depend from parent process (`cmd`, `powershell` or something else).